# Error While Making API call In reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, django-rest-framework

I am using the NPM Request library to make an API call in which I want to pass Header as well as form. Until the time I wanted only formdata the API call was working fine but as soon as added the header in the API call it is showing the following error:-

> " Failed to construct 'Headers': Please use the 'new' operator.... "

Here Is My API call:-

```
send:function(endpoint,callback, token, formdata, component){
                this._request.post(endpoint, Headers : { Authorization :token 
                      }, {form: formdata},function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        callback(response.body, component);
                    }else if(!error && response.statusCode == 400){

                    }
                })
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this :

You can pass the headers as simple as json object but the format should be like this :

```
this._request.post(endpoint, { headers : { Authorization : token } , form: formdata },

    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(response.body, component);
        }else if(!error && response.statusCode == 400){

        }
    })

}
```